# McAfee anti-virus for linux server?

Tags: linux, security, vps, mcafee

We have a CentOS server for our web startup hosted on softlayer.com. Knowing how secure Linux is even without anti-virus programs: Do I still need to install McAfee as advertised in softlayer's site (http://www.softlayer.com/services/security/mcafeeAntiVirus)? Is it worth installing? What benefits will it provide me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anti-virus software may be useful on Linux mail server or Linux file server serving computers with MS software.

Answer (score -1):

Well, given that McAfee is windows software, how you want to install it? What WIndows Viruses you think will attack your Linux?

So, the answer is a clear and simple "no".

Btw., even for a windows web server installing anti vorus is not needed IF you manage tight control of the server.... or run a web app that allows file uploads (where it is advisable).

Comment: VirusScan Enterprise is available for various distros, including CentOS: http://www.mcafee.com/uk/products/virusscan-enterprise-for-linux.aspx#vt=vtab-SystemRequirements  EDIT: The Softlayer site is only advertising the Windows software, from what I can tell.

Comment: I see it's Linux-compatible from here: http://www.mcafee.com/us/products/host-ips-for-server.aspx#vtab-SystemRequirements=&vt=vtab-SystemRequirements